# What is PPP and why does it not have a MAC address?

Tags: router, network, networking, mac-address, ppp

I just wanted clarification on what exactly PPP is and why it does not have a MAC address due to having seen that under a response to a question of how routers transverse packets to their destinations.

Comment: MAC addresses are used by the IEEE data-link protocols, but other data-link protocols use other or no addressing. Frame relay uses DLCI, ATM uses VPI/VCI, PPP and HDLC do not use addressing, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PPP is a data link layer protocol that's designed to run on top of a simple serial link as physical layer. Since there are exactly two nodes on that point-to-point link, no addressing is required.

The PPP header does have an 8-bit address field but it's not used anywhere (always 0xff).

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: It is quite literally in the name: *Point-to-Point Protocol*.